# Stm32g474 discovery kit HRTIM ISR HRTIM1_TIMA_IRQHandler not hit for channel set interrupt setx1 and channel reset interrupt rstx1

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

I have enabled the interrupts for channel set (SETx1) and channel reset (RSTx1) by setting bits RSTx1IE and SET1xIE. I am trying to drive the outputs to active-inactive state via software by writing to SST and RST bits of the TIMERA.

Inside the TIMAISR register I can see the SETx1 and RSTx1 interrupt event flags are set. This indicates the fact that output active-inactive state changes are driving the interrupts.

But I cannot see the respective ISR HRTIM1_TIMA_IRQHandler getting hit. While other interrupts are working fine and I can see the ISR gets executed in those situations, it is only for the SETx1 and RSTx1/SETx2 and RSTx2 I see this problem.

Is there any settings I could me missing that might cause this issue?

[Image that shows global interrupt for TimerA is enabled in NVIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXEba.jpg)

[Image that shows HRTIM peripheral interrupt are enabled for SET and RST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDAGp.jpg)

[Image that shows Interrupt occured inside HRTIM peripheral for SET and RST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzXUp.jpg)

Comment: Did you enable the interrupt at the NVIC?

Comment: Yep, I did enable the global interrupt flag -> "HRTIM timer A global interrupt". While other interrupts from the same group are working, it is only for the SETx1/RSTx1 and SETx2/RSTx2 the issue is present.

Comment: Please, post what registers you setup, which interrupts, where and how you enable in the HRTIM. I just opened HRTIM and saw literally 82 registers, a handful of them have various interrupts. I did find the ones you probably use, but I wanna see your setup code to make sure sure it does what needs to be done, I really don't want to write the whole setup from scratch (82 registers! and I have life!). You are clearly forgetting/misconfiguring something.

Comment: Please find the images that talk about the registers that are updated to enable the interrupts in the original post. I enabled the HRTIM TIMERA global interrupts in STM32CubeMX. Rest of the peripheral level interrupts are enabled by hand code. As noted before, configuring the interrupts either in NVIC or the HRTIM peripheral is not an issue because the interrupts from other events from the same ISR group are working fine, it is only for the SETx1/RSTx1 and SETx2/RSTx2 the issue is present.

Comment: You enabled interrupts in NVIC, but did you enable interrupts in HRTIM? The fact that interrupt flags are set doesn't mean that interrupt signal is sent from HRTIM to NVIC. This has to be enabled separately.